# Why by calling new File(".").getAbsolutePath() I get completely different path from my project's location?

Tags: java, eclipse, path, filesystems, absolute-path

My project is located here:

```
D:/WorkSpace/PuzzleApp
```

but when I am calling

```
new File(".").getAbsolutePath();
```

I get:

```
D:\!Documents\Desktop\.
```

Why? And how to fix this?

I'm using Eclipse.

Comment: Because execution directory is not the same as project directory.

Comment: @aled thanks, is there any way to change execution directory?

Comment: You should explain why and that is probably a different question.

Comment: @aled I want to write an image into the project's folder
`ImageIO.write(subimage, "jpg", new File("D:/WorkSpace/PuzzleApp/PuzzleApp/src/main/webapp/subimages/subimage_" + counter + ".jpg"));` works, but ("webapp/subimages/subimage"); doesn't

Comment: *@aled I want to write an image into the project's folder* You don't. Real software doesn't care about IDEs and projects. You need to write to *some location*. That location is best placed off the user's home directory

Comment: You should not use the project directory at execution time.

Comment: @g00se so, what's I need to do? write the image to something like D:/WorkSpace/PuzzleApp or how to correctly set the path

Comment: Do not have your application create files in your project directory. If your application needs to create files either have the user choose a destination for those files or create a profile directory in the corresponding operating system specific location. E.g. on Windows, you would want to write to `C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\<companyname>\<applicationname>`.

Comment: @pure21_h Imagine if all software required you to have the exact directory structure the developer has, including the src code. Option 1: Write relative to the current folder (e.g. the current working directory) Option 2: Write relative to the user's home folder (`System.getProperty("user.home")`) Option 3: Write relative to some environment variable (`System.getenv("OUTFOLDER")`) Option 4: Do it your way, because it's "easier"

Comment: @ThomasBehr alright thanks, the problem is I am struggling to get the images from directory like u wrote, because JSP wants exactly webapp/images/image.jpg path

Comment: What is JSP? And what has "JSP **wants** ..." to do with **writing** files? "JSP wants ..." means to me "JSP wants to **read**". What is the purpose of those images you were trying to create?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch thank you, but I need this images to display on my JSP page and I am not sure I could get it from that

Comment: @ThomasBehr yes, for the beginning I create these images and then I display them on the JSP page - home.jsp in this way `img scr = 'images/image_1'`

Comment: So it turns out you want to write static files dynamically ;)

Comment: Are these images *static application resources*? In that case, create those static images, save them to any directory you want, then move them into the resources directory of your project. Do **not** have your application create the images.

Comment: Write a servlet to read (and display) the images from the configured folder. You've posted code that does not seem particularly relevant to your actual question.

Comment: @ThomasBehr my program should split a given image into sub-images. and display them on the jsp page

Comment: Ok, then you need to either split the input image *in memory* and display the resulting sub-images without writing those sub-images to files or you need to write the sub-images to a directory *on the server* to which your JSP page has read access. The latter is more or less what @ElliottFrisch suggested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you open File with relative path `"."` this path is relative to the current process' working directory.
Usually, the process working directory is inherited from the parent process (e.g. if you run your app with Terminal - the current terminal's working directory will be your process' working dir).

Using a relative path inside your application is considered a bad idea because you can not control this process' working directory.
But using an absolute hardcoded path also goes with some problems and can't be called a good practice.

There are several ways to solve the issue:

1. Use a path relative to some NOT hardcoded absolute path. This absolute path should be externalized to environment variables, properties files, etc.

```
//Getting the directory path from the external system variable
String myAbsoultePath = System.getenv("LOCAL_STORAGE_DIR");
```

2. Use a path relative to your application root. It allows you to READ files even located inside .jar or .war archives.

```
//This path looks absolute, but the path's root is your project's root
InputStream stream = MyClass.class.getResourceAsStream("/dir/another/file.txt");
```

But you should understand, that your application won't run inside your IDE project folder. It will be deployed in a production server/user's desktop/android device environment and usually, it is packed in a jar/war/ear/... archive. It means that you won't have access to your `src` folder or something like this.